# Cannot adopt a swift class to an objective C protocol of type X <NSObject>

Tags: ios, swift

I am very new to Swift and so I may phrase things weirdly here. Apologies!

I've got the following (simplified) protocol in Objective C:

```
@protocol OtherProtocol <NSObject>
@optional

...

@end
```

I would like to create a class in Swift (4.2) that adheres to this protocol, so I defined my class like:

```
class MyClass : OtherProtocol {

}
```

Naturally, XCode will complain because my class doesn't have the correct methods.

It looks like I need to implement a bunch of `NSObject` methods in addition to those defined in `OtherProtocol`. When XCode adds in the missing method stubs from `NSObject`, there's one in particular giving issues:

```
func `self`() -> Self {
    ...
}
```

The problem with this method is `Method cannot be an implementation of an @objc requirement because its result type cannot be represented in Objective-C`.

I'd like the quickest way out of this, as I won't end up using any of those standard `NSObject` functions anyways. Any thoughts?

Comment: Quickest? Inherit `NSObject`: `class MyClass: NSObject, OtherProtocol`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is no need to implement NSObject's methods.
To be able to subclass/inherit from Objective-C classes/protocols you just need to inherit from NSObject. This is to make sure that your Swift class can be used in Objective-C environment as well. Also, **Swift structs** can't adopt Objective-C protocols, as there is no such type in Obj-C

This should work

```
class MyClass: NSObject, OtherProtocol {
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the right answer, though Objective-C actually does have `struct`s, too. They're not nearly as full-featured, and can't adopt protocols or inherit from other objects, but they do exist

Comment: @MichaelHulet Obj-C doesn't have its own `struct`, it can only use C `struct`s and Swift `struct`s cannot be represented in Obj-C.

Comment: Those are what I’m talking about. Obejctive-C is just C plus some object-oriented features. IIRC when it was first designed at NeXT, it was implemented with the C preprocessor. Apple makes extensive use of these `struct`s in their API, though, for things like `CGRect` or `CGPoint`